# HTML Form. Add/Remove Form *Sections* (not single fields) on drop-down selection

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm creating a quote form where a user will select a service (logo, print, website etc.) via a drop-down and click add. A div of predetermined form values related to their choice will appear below in order for me to gain more detail on what they're looking for. Once they make a choice, and customize it's options, they can add additional services if needed. I'd like to utilize jQuery in the end to make it look nice, but regular javascript is fine for now. Please help me out, I'm not an expert with forms but I'm assuming this may end up being straight forward to implement?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example at jsFiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/5Dmja/

There are lots of improvements that could be made but it seems like you are just looking for a rough outline...

And really YMMV when asking others to do your work for you ;)